# Simple code throws IllegalStateException when device's orientation changed

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Wait app for start. Rotate device. Click on view. Exception.

[Project code here](http://rgho.st/662hPhCGx)

Why do am I getting this exception?

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity (Label = "OrientationChangeFragmentCommit", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    const string currentFragmentTag = "currentFragment";

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        if (GetCurrentFragment() == null)
        {
            BlueFragment frag = new BlueFragment();
            frag.AuthTcs.Task.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                try
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(() => FragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate());
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    //exception here
                }
            });
            AddFrag(this, frag, Resource.Id.fragmentContainer);
        }
    }

    void AddFrag(Activity act, Fragment frag, int containerId)
    {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = act.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTx.Add(containerId, frag, currentFragmentTag);
        fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTx.Commit();
    }

    Fragment GetCurrentFragment()
    {
        var f = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag (currentFragmentTag);
        return f;
    }
}
```

BlueFragment.cs

```
public class BlueFragment : Fragment
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<bool> AuthTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        RetainInstance = true;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = new LinearLayout (inflater.Context);
        view.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        view.SetBackgroundColor (Color.Blue);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        view.LayoutParameters = par;
        view.AddView(new View(inflater.Context));

        view.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            AuthTcs.TrySetResult(true);
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Exception says: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right code is:

```
frag.AuthTcs.Task.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        RunOnUiThread (() => frag.Activity.FragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate ());
    });
```

Because lambda function was storing the reference to an old activity, and therefore to an old FragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line in your code

```
fragmentTx.Commit();
```

with the following code

```
fragmentTx.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

For more information please refer the following link:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: even if doing so exception is thrown

Comment: figured it out (posted as an answer)